How to stop singing and humming, speaking myself?
As a layperson, I try to achieve sotapanna and do vipassana meditation for one month approximately.
I like to hear song, so I leave it. But, I often sing and hum accidentally. I try to stop it but it's so difficult
And second, I often speak loudly when there isn't anyone in the room. I try to stop it but it's so difficult

See MN 19, and MN 20
https://lucid24.org/mn/index.html
● MN 20 Vitakka-saṇṭhāna: Thought-composition
5 ways to remove unwanted thoughts: replace, see danger, forget, slow down, mind crush.
﻿ MN 20 – MN 20 Vitakka-saṇṭhāna: thought-composition
    MN 20.5 (Adhi­citta = syn.of samādhi, 5 nimittas are methods to remove unwanted thoughts)
        MN 20.5.1 (Replace unskillful with skillful thought ↔ fine peg replace coarse one)
        MN 20.5.2 (Seeing danger in un-skilful ↔ wear carcass around neck)
        MN 20.5.3 (Forget, give no attention ↔ close eyes, don’t see)
        MN 20.5.4 (Progressive slow down ↔ walking, standing...lying)
        MN 20.5.5 (Mind crush mind ↔ strong man crush weak one)
    MN 20.10 (conclusion)
        MN 20.10.1 (brief summary of 5 methods)
        MN 20.10.5 (Master of thought thinks what he wants, doesn’t think what he doesn’t want)

I remember when I was 5 year old and reading loud along with my brother. my mom told 'read silently'. I immidiately started reading silently. and my brother was staring at me. as If i did some magic. it just happened.
Simlarly just few month back I realized that when I think . there are sensation in body. particularly in head and throat. ( I could discern this because I do goenka style meditation). As If I am speaking. this is how in experience there is no difference between loud thinking and speaking.
and then I remember my childhood magic. and told myself to think silently.
and found that its difficult by not impossible.
how I do that is , be mindful of throat an head region. while you are thinking. and try to cut the sentences. just first word is allowed. and drop remaining words of sentences.
I dont know whether you can do this or not. but its fact. the linguistic thinking is actually speech/ vohra/ vachI sankhara. and not vitaka/vicara.
the thought is subtler then the sentences which are prepared in your mind.

Fill your mind with something like Mithree(Maththa) meditation. Fill your all the time that is not doing Vipassana.
Like when walking, washing, drinking ect, ect. Fill all the nun meditate spaced time.
That's what recommended by Ven Balangoda ananda mithree thero and others.
You can use one of Sathipattana meditation, Mithree meditation, Asuba meditation, Maranassuthiya meditation as this filling meditation.
This way all the useless thoughts should stop. And there will not be time for rise of five hindrances.
It will help Vipassana also, because meththa meditation brings some concentration to the mind.
Best good luck for your meditation.
Thanks .☸️.
Questions are welcome.
